# How do I Combine/Merge PDFs with Fillable Form Fields using pyPDF2, Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pypdf, pdf-form

I am trying to merge two pdf files which have form elements on them using pypdf2 and python 2.7. While merging those two pdf files the form elements of file 2 are being overridden by form elements of file 1.

Sample of the code I am using is :

```
def merger(input_paths, output_path):
    try:
        pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
        for path in input_paths:
            logging.info("Adding file: %s" % path)
            pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(path)
            for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
                inFile = pdf_reader.getPage(page)
                pdf_writer.addPage(inFile)

        with open(output_path, 'wb') as fh:
            pdf_writer.write(fh)
        print("final out put ::::" + output_path)
    except Exception, e:
        logging.error("Error merging pdf file.")
        traceback.print_exc()
        pass
```

Can you point me in the right direction ?